# SseEventSource.open() takes too long

Tags: java, server-sent-events

I am using javax.ws.rs.sse.SseEventSource to listen to events sent by my API. Here is my implementation:

```
        String bearer = getBearerToken();
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register((ClientRequestFilter) clientRequestContext -> {
             MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = clientRequestContext.getHeaders();
             headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearer);
        });

        SseEventSource.target(client.target(url)).build(); 
        sseEventSource.register(this::onMessage, this::onError);
        sseEventSource.open();
```

Everthing works great except for the fact that `sseEventSource.open()` blocks for a substantial amount of time (15s-40s). When I print the thread state I get the following:

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=31 cpu=2616.95ms elapsed=34.80s tid=0x00007fbd38009800 nid=0x1703 waiting on condition  [0x00007000046a7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.6/Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000070d8cbe00> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@11.0.6/LockSupport.java:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(java.base@11.0.6/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(java.base@11.0.6/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1039)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(java.base@11.0.6/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1345)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(java.base@11.0.6/CountDownLatch.java:232)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.sse.client.SseEventSourceImpl$EventHandler.awaitConnected(SseEventSourceImpl.java:417)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.sse.client.SseEventSourceImpl.open(SseEventSourceImpl.java:174)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.sse.client.SseEventSourceImpl.open(SseEventSourceImpl.java:163)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.sse.client.SseEventSourceImpl.open(SseEventSourceImpl.java:158)
```

I was wondering what is the thread waiting for, is it expecting something to be published in the stream before proceeding (if so, is it possible to configure it otherwise)? Anyway, my main question is how to have a faster `SseEventSource.open()`?

---

**Update:** I found out that `SseEventSource.open()` is waiting to receive a message for the first time. It is unfortunate because the actual connection is established quickly and I have to wait about 30s for the method to return. So far I was not able to find out a good solution for this.

Comment: As the stacktrace shows, it's blocking at `awaitConnected()`. You might want to observe the network traffic to see if there's some weirdness, since obviously it shouldn't take 15 seconds to open a connection.

Comment: @Kayaman it looks like it is waiting to receive a message before releasing. Not sure how to solve this though

Comment: To me it looks like it's making a connection handshake (which is why I would inspect the network traffic), but taking its sweet time. Why does it look to you like it's trying to receive a message when it hasn't even connected yet? Is that just a guess? You can't receive (application protocol) messages before you've connected. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: 1) if I manually write something in the stream SseEventSource.open() returns immediately; 2) if I do not write anything SseEventSource.open() returns immediately after the heartbeat message is received.

Comment: Well, as the API doesn't give you much options, you might have to offload the connection openings to their own threads.

Comment: Unfortunately it creates a race condition in my code. I prefer increasing the heartbeat frequency

Comment: This seems to be a problem only with certain versions of JerseyEventSink implementation. The easy solution is to send a heartbeat on handshake from the server as so: new OutboundEvent.Builder()
      .id("ping")
      .comment("health-check")
      .reconnectDelay(_RECONNECT_IN_MILLIS)
      .build()